# module-Swift.h file not found in mm file in building Unity-Swift framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c++

I followed this URL.
https://medium.com/@kevinhuyskens/implementing-swift-in-unity-53e0b668f895

But I have issues.[I have attached issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4xm4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some info might help;
Clean project folder,
Check the location address of the bridging header file in the build settings
Be sure framework is integrated to project.
Also check if the bridging header has all the class that has to communicate each other.